# Query to find records having 0 nested association on a specific nested record

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

User model :

```
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :planning_entries
```

PlanningEntry model :

```
Class PlanningEntry < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :planning
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :plannings
```

Planning model

```
Class Planning < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :planning_entries
```

- The planning table has a field `day:date`
- The PlanningEntry has a field `state: [:approved, :canceled, etc.]`

I would like to make a scope to retrieve all users not assigned to the current day's Planning using the `day` field.

This mean that i can't exclude users having `planning_entries` from old `plannings`

On other thing, there are several states for the `PlanningEntry` table and only the `:approved` state is considered as a true association for a user to a planning in this request

So far i did this query :

```
 User.joins( planning_entries: :planning ).
    where( "(plannings.day = ? AND planning_entries.state != 'approved')",
    Planning.current_day)
```

I tried to add some more `OR / AND` condition in the query to deal with all the cases needed but nothing worked so far.

Any help would be grandly appreciated

Comment: I tried and failed to parse this sentence: `a user who has a planning_entry with everything but approved state`. I also failed to find your version of Postgres. And `the current day's Planning`? Is `day` supposed to be unique / primary key in `planning`? Can you clarify?

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter  sorry for my english. I meant that there are several states for the PlanningEntry table and only the `:approved` state is considered as a true association for a user to a planning in this request. Hope it was clearer :)

Comment: Please *edit the question* to clarify. Shouldn't be hidden in comments only.

Comment: `Query to find records having 0 nested association` ... Syntax Error in line#0.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to ... retrieve all users not assigned to the current
>   day's Planning.

In SQL, one of various ways:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   Users u
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT 1
   FROM   Planning p
   JOIN   PlanningEntry pe ON pe.planning_id = p.id
   WHERE  p.day = CURRENT_DATE
   AND    pe.users_id = u.id
   AND    state = 'approved'  -- only 'approved' matters
   );
```

This will return all users except (the few?) that are approved for (any of) today's meeting(s).

I am guessing columns names you did not disclose.

You may have to double-quote identifiers if you obfuscation layer is in the habbit of double-quoting mixed case identifiers.

More:

- [Select rows which are not present in other table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19363481/select-rows-which-are-not-present-in-other-table/19364694#19364694)

Comment: `I would like to ... retrieve all users not assigned to the current day's Planning.` meant to me that i need all users not having association with a specific planning.

Comment: @C404: The query should do that now.